# Need help in bit complicated SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/134bad

**Data if you were not able to access the link:**

```
create table climate (city varchar(10), status char(1), Curdate date);

insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'S', '2013-08-05');
insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'S', '2013-08-06');
insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'S', '2013-08-07');
insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'S', '2013-08-08');

insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'R', '2013-08-09');
insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'R', '2013-08-10');

insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'S', '2013-08-12');
insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'S', '2013-08-13');

insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'R', '2013-08-14');
insert into climate values ('Chennai', 'R', '2013-08-15');

insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'S', '2013-08-05');
insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'S', '2013-08-06');
insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'R', '2013-08-07');
insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'R', '2013-08-08');

insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'R', '2013-08-09');
insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'S', '2013-08-10');

insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'R', '2013-08-12');
insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'R', '2013-08-13');

insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'R', '2013-08-14');
insert into climate values ('Banglore', 'S', '2013-08-15');
```

The link has approximate data.

From the table we need to retrieve city name and latest maximum date when the status ('R' / 'S') remained same for more than 2 days.

ie. R-Raining
     S-Sunny

We need to retrieve City and maximum date when the city was Rainy or Sunny continuously for more than 2 days.

eg: from the example data,

Query should retrieve

```
City                  Date
Banglore           2013-08-14
Chennai            2013-08-08
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005/2008:

```
select city, max(dt) max_dt
from (
    select city
        , dateadd(dd, x, Curdate) dt
        , min(case x when 0 then status end) s0
        , min(case x when 1 then status end) s1
        , min(case x when 2 then status end) s2
    from climate c
    cross join (select 0 x union all select 1 union all select 2)x
    group by city, dateadd(dd, x, Curdate)
) t
where s0 = s1 and s1 = s2
group by city
```

If you use SQL Server 2012 query will be much simplier. Look for LAG/LEAD functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the Islands and Gaps problem and you can use Common Table Expressions to solve it as well:

```
;WITH DateIslandByCityStatus_CTE (City, Status, CurDate, Island) AS
(
    SELECT City
         , Status
         , CurDate
         , Island = DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City, Status ORDER BY CurDate), CurDate) 
      FROM Climate
),
DateIslandWithTwoDaysOfWeather (City, Status, MaxDate) AS
(
    SELECT City
         , Status
         , MAX(CurDate)
      FROM DateIslandByCityStatus_CTE
      GROUP BY City, Status, Island
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
)
SELECT City
     , Max(MaxDate)
  FROM DateIslandWithTwoDaysOfWeather
 GROUP BY City
 ORDER BY City
```

See Also: ["The SQL of Gaps and Islands in Sequences - Dwain Camps"](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL 2005 or above:

```
select city, status, max(endDate) as Date
from
(
  select city, status, MIN(curdate) as startDate, MAX(curDate) as endDate
  from
  (
    select city, status, curdate,
    DATEADD(dd, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by city, status ORDER BY city, curdate), curdate)
    from climate
    group by city, status, curdate
  ) consecutiveDates(city, status, curdate, grp)
  group by city, status, grp
  having COUNT(*) > 2
) groupedConsecutiveDates
group by city, status
```